# MySQL Entity Framework design close the window and can't continue

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I used **MySQL Connector** and **MySQL** for **Visual Studio** with the **Entity Framework 6** for working on my project.

Yesterday i formatted my computer:

- Reinstalled Visual Studio 2012
- Installed the update 4
- Installed the Entity Framework 6 tools
- Installed with the MySQL installer the Visual Studio Extension and
  the .NET connector.

But when i select "update from database" in the Entity Framework design, after connecting to the server (on localhost) and remove the "put connection string in application config" checkbox, when i press Next the window close instantly and nothing happed.

What is happening?!

THank you in advance.

Comment: The answer of Alfredo Rodriguez worked for me [Check out the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241500/cant-create-entity-data-model-using-mysql-and-ef6)