# Can't Create Entity Data Model - using MySql and EF6

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, mysql-connector, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm trying to add an edmx Entity model to my C#/Web Project in Visual Studio 2013. My problem is that the file is not created.

I do the following steps:

1. Give the item a name
2. Choose 'EF Designer from database'
3. Choose the connection from the drop down (localhost) that already tested successfully connecting to MySQL databse
4. The "Save connection settings in webc.config as" option is checked
5. I click 'Next' AND the window disappeared and I get back to the code window

**No edmx file is created.** (although it works with SQL Server, but not for MySQL)

I have `Entity Framework 6.1.2` installed, `MySql.Data`, `MySql.Data.Entities`, `MySql.Data.Entity`, `MySql.Web` -- all installed.

I also rebuilt the project before trying to add an entity model file.

I've installed the latest MySQL package with the latest `.NET connector`.

Running: Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Any possibility that the file was created but not included in the solution automatically?

Comment: @Yasir Yes, it is there. I tried "update model from database" again from within the designer (diagram), but it just closes the window without doing anything.

Comment: can you attach screenshots of your solution explorer and the folder structure you have? Next, if you see the edmx file open, close it, right click on it and open with XML editor. Search for the words 'error' and 'exception' and post what you find.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution yet ? Please let me know..

Comment: A workaround for Core is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58324837/7149454

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved this issue by following some steps below:

1. Uninstall `MySql.Data.Entities` from Nuget by using command below in Package Manager Console:
   `Uninstall-Package MySql.Data.Entities`
2. Add project reference to the latest `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll` from your MySql connector installation path at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.8\Assemblies\v4.5`

Comment: thanks for the tip. worked for me. What I don't get is why have a nuget if its not going to work  ...

Comment: I solved the problem by installing same version of MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity.

Comment: Worked for me, but had to uninstall and reinstall Connector/Net.

Answer (score 81):

I just had the same situation when trying to configure Visual Studio Professional 2017 environment with MySQL, ADO.NET (Database First) and EF6.

Note: Please follow steps in the same order.

1. Uninstall/remove "Connector/NET" and "MySQL for Visual Studio" if installed.
2. Install "MySQL for Visual Studio" v2.0.5 CTP ([MySQL for Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=470092)).
   Note: Install MySQL for Visual Studio before Connector/NET.
3. Install "Connector/NET" v6.9.10 ([Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=474110)).
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOT1I.jpg Note: I tried using Connector/NET v6.8, v6.10 and v8 first, but none of them worked with Visual Studio 2017 and ADO.Net. [Here you can find all Connector Versions and Compatibilities with Visual Studio IDEs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html), but so far this list is inaccurate.
4. Create new Visual Studio Professional 2017 project.
5. Download and Install "EntityFramework" v6.2.0 through NuGet, by going to Project Tab/Manage NuGet Packages/Browse -> Entity Framework.
6. Add references to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9.10\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.dll`
   and
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9.10\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll`; by Right Clicking over References inside Solution Explorer and selecting Add Reference/Browse ->Browse button.
7. Add MySQL EF6 provider info inside App.config under entity framework providers as follow:

```html
<entityFramework>
       <providers>
         <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
              type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
       </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

8. Rebuild project by going to Build tab/Rebuild ProjectName.

And that's it. VS2017 is ready to go. Hope this works for everybody, as it did for me today.

**References**:

1. [Can't Create Entity Data Model - using MySql and EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38619052/3802757)
2. [No Entity Framework provider found for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' ADO.NET provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19898907)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Well-documented and explains everything in very good detail. Solved my problem. I know this was added after the "accepted answer", but this should now replace it. Thank you!

Comment: @BoydP except the OP asked about Visual Studio 2013, not 2017

Comment: Deserves many upvotes, have been looking for this for so long, the only solution that's very clear an that actually  works!

Comment: Thank you. I followed your steps and it works like a charm.

Comment: You're the main! This was the only solution that worked for me on Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. (October, 2018)

Comment: Had the same issue with VS 2017. Worked for me as a charm! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked in VS2015 project. Thanks.

Comment: This answer must be marked as correct answer. Worked fine.

Comment: This absolutely works! I'm very surprised and happy for the moment. Although, it's sad that we as programmers have to get our hands so dirty just to use a feature of software that should already work. I performed Step 6. just a bit differently because I didn't want to browse. I simply typed "MySql" in the search box of the "Reference Manager" form and selected the two required assemblies that way.

Comment: So frustrating!  It appears 6.9.10 is the key here as the other definitely don't work (hours of trial and error led me here).

Comment: I used this and My Visual Studio Part was working.. Finally! But for some Reason my MySQL console was crashing. Reinstalled MySQL version 5.7 and that's got fixed.

Answer (score 12):

VS 2015 still has this bug.
It is caused by version mismatch.

On my system, I had MySQL Connector 6.9.6.
Issuing the command in NuGet Package Manger Console:

```
Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity
```

installs version 6.9.8 by default. Your connector must match the actual version of the NuGet Package.
You can download an updated version of the connector from:
https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Here select the "Ado.net driver for MySQL", and download the corresponding version (in this case 6.9.8).
Reopen Visual Studio and now the wizard does not crash.
No reboot required.

Comment: The link to the download if the connector was out of date solved my problem.

Comment: This solution worked for me with VS2015 and connector 6.9.9.  The other suggestions on SO did not work for my setup. up voted.

Comment: had the same issue of the wizard failing but had the correct version. Had to uninstall the connector and reinstall and all good. A repair didnt work.

Comment: worked !, here is the link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html

Answer (score 5):

This is for an ASP.NET MVC application, which does not have an app.config file.
I will not recount the failed attempts, but what worked for me was the following:-

- With VS **not** running, download and install "MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.5" - the latest version at time of writing.
- Start VS2017 and uninstall the "MySql.Data.Entity" and "MySql.Data" NuGet packages, if
  they have been previously installed in VS2017.
- Download and install the latest MySql connector/NET using the links above (version 8.0.13 at time of writing).
- In your project add references to the "MySql.Data.dll" and  "MySql.Data.EntityFramework.dll" dlls as described above by Lopez93, **but** N.B. the "MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll" mentioned did not exist in 8.0.13, only "MySql.Data.EntityFramework.dll".
- Now edit the web.config file and make sure that in the  section, there is this line

<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"  type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.**EntityFramework**">

- Remove or comment out any other '<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"...' lines.
- Rebuild the project.

Try using the wizard again.

For me this worked.

Good luck!

Comment: This solved my issues instantly (using MySql.Data v 8.0.15), check the provider in the `entityFramework` section. This is gold, been working for 2 days now on this, reckon I've tried all the old advice, was about to give up.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this problem by performing the following:

1. Open MySQL Installer and install the latest version of Connector/NET
2. Uninstall / reinstall the latest version MySQL.Data.* packages with versions that match the version of the newly installed Connector/NET package
3. Restart Visual Studios
4. Rebuild solution

Answer (score 4):

Taking suggestions about NuGet versioning from others answers.
I solved this issue by deleting the `.Data` and `Data.Entitiy.EF6` installed by Nuget.

Then right click on References and browse for:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.dll` 
and
`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll`

I was then able to complete the ADO.Net wizard, with the .edmx models.

Answer (score 3):

I know the solution.

Nuget installs edge version of MySql.Data.* packages, while you probably have previous version of the connector (In my case packages were v. 6.9.6 and Connector was 6.9.5). This comes to the point where you have version mismatch.

Be aware that if you use ***Install-Package MySql.Data.Entities*** in NuGet you will get even older version like 6.8.3, so you have to add the references by yourself and keep an eye on which one you are trying to add to your solution.

Comment: I have tried all manner of combinations and this still doesn't work. The system tries and shows all the right dialogs but still creates no model. I've just rolled my own, not as good but it will do as I have no more time to give to this

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue upgrading from version 6 of MySql to version 8.0.17.0. I struggled with this for almost two days trying all of the old remedies until I came across [this article](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/50157720/entity-framework-to-mysql-connection-failed-to-database). 
If you are using EF6 and version 8.0.? of MySql, according to this post:

---

MySql.Data.Entity 6.10.7 isn't compatible with MySql.Data 8.0.11.

Oracle renamed the package to MySql.Data.EntityFramework for v8.x. You need to uninstall MySql.Data.Entity and install MySql.Data.EntityFramework.

---

Once I did this simple step, the data connection started working and the EDMX designer started working as well (although I have to go back to 2017 Visual Studio because the Designer Tools for VS 2019 were not available at the time of this post.)

Hope this newer post helps some of you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using MySQL Connector 6.9.8.0. While all my versions matched, this still failed. I had installed a new version of Visual Studio AFTER the MySQL connector (From 2010 to 2013). For me, the solution was to uninstall the MySQL Connector for NET and then reinstall it (Exact same version). Then restart Visual Studio.

Seems like this is another version of the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this solution:

1. Add a new empty EF model.
2. In the emdx design rigth click and update the model from database.
3. choose your database and the model will be generate.

That's work for me :)

Comment: doesn't work for me, neither does the solution below. The wizard comes up but then does nothing

Answer (score 0):

another thing to try:

--->install the entityframework 6.2.0 via nuget.

--->Verify in your web.config/app.config file that you have the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0` provider. if it's not installed, then install it via nuget, the exact same version as the entity framework previously installed (6.2.0 in this case).

--->then add the references: (in this case from the connector/NET version 6.9.10)
`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.dll` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll` and rebuild.

--->try adding this provider too:
`<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />` rebuild, again.

--->and finally, try adding the .edmx file with a new connection.

This worked in my case where i installed VS2017 and MySQL in a brand new laptop, and had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my web.config file from:

> <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />

To:

> <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></provider>

Comment: This did not work for my Visual Studio 2017 Community project that is experiencing the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

### **For EntityFramework 5.0**

***Step 1***

Install MySQL Connector/NET **version 6.8.4** on https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/

Install MySQL for Visual Studio on https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

***Step 2***

Add Refenreces:

- MySql.Data
- MySql.Data.Entity.EF5

***Step 3***

Add codes (at the below) to web.config

```
 <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></remove>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.4.0, Culture=neutral" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```