# Why the window closes when generating EDMX?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, edmx

I can not generate edmx from the MySQL database. I tried everything. From the reinstallation of VS 2017 to the installation of packages needed to connect to this particular type of database.

With the help of tools Tools => Connect to Database, I connect. I get all the tables. However, if I want to generate an edmx file for this database, then at point 7 of [this example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-and-update-an-edmx-file-using-entity-framework-data-model-in-visual-stud/) this window closes and returns to the main window. It is not possible to choose tables as it is shown on screen.

Has anyone encountered such a situation already? All possible advice unfortunately did not help me. I'm posting a screen with library versions.

[image]

Comment: Looks like similar issue when using vs 2013 [Can't Create Entity Data Model - using MySql and EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241500/cant-create-entity-data-model-using-mysql-and-ef6)

Comment: I have no idea why ... but it works! I was doing this sequence for several times and it was the same every time. It works anyway anyway so thank you very much for your help with the problem.