# Adding ADO.NET Entity Data Model in VS 2017 and nothing happens

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, ado.net

After selecting the MySQL data source in the Entity Data Model wizard in Visual Studio and clicking on "Next", the wizard just closes. What's going wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: this happens for Firebird, too if you have wrong providers installed. If you use EF6, make sure you have EF6 providers installed

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Anyone solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but a workaround to this bug, create a core 2.x console app, project file content below (won't work with core 3 at the moment):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.17" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` is to scaffold Microsoft SQL Server strings, `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` is to scaffold MySql Server connection strings.
then in the package manager console (inside visual studio, tested 2017 and 2019) type:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;port=3306;user=USERNAME;password=YOUR_PASSWORD;database=DATABASE_NAME" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models -f
```

that was fow MySql. For MSSQL type:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=SERVER_ADDRESS;Database=DATABASE_NAME;user=USERNAME; password=YOUR_PASSWORD;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -f
```

this will generate the context model and the containing classes so you can you can finally use database first in your core app (yes, time to move to core).

Answer (score 0):

- Install old version of MySql Connector like **6.9.10** from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/  , Because the newer 8.0 appearto have problems.
- In Package Manager Console Install:

```
Install-Package MySQL.Data -Version 6.9.9
Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity -Version 6.9.10
```

- Don't forget to add this lines in web.config

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```