# How to conect MVC and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I have started a project with MVC
I go to models > add items > ADO.NET entity
then i configure my mysqldata base and when i click finish it wont add to models. 
what i'm doing wrong?
thanks 
 [https://imgur.com/a/ypwmKFx]

I use xampp

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did u select tables to add?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer [Can't Create Entity Data Model - using MySql and EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241500/cant-create-entity-data-model-using-mysql-and-ef6) .It is Possible in EF6 .I was facing similar issue so created the same usingEF6 and followed these steps.